# Ubuntu 22.04 after update screen brightness control disappeared from the bar and brightness is at 100%

Tags: updates, laptop, screen, brightness, acpi

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS running in my Dynabook laptop Intel i7-1165G7 as my daily development machine.
Today, back to work after a few days of vacation, I did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.
After reboot the laptop screen stayed at 100% brightness and the brightness control bar disappeared from system bar.

Some weird update released at the end of July or beginning of August 2023 messed up this configuration with the acpi driver for controlling the brightness of the screen.

Current kernel version after update is:

```
Linux 6.2.0-26-generic 
#26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC 
Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

> After viewing some web pages I had to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file via:
>
> ```
> sudo vim /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> and change the following line from:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=native"
> ```
>
> Then I ran:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> and rebooted the laptop.
>
> After that the screen brightness control and brightness level was
> restored as before the update.
>
> Hope this can help someone with same issue.

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1481435/2) with some formatting fixes.</sup>