# Brightness controller disappeared after 23.04 ubuntu upgrade

Tags: brightness, 23.04

My brightness slider/controller disappeared after 23.04 ubuntu upgrade (top right hand corner + in power settings), used to work before in 22.10.
(similar problem to this i suppose:
[22.04 jammy shows no brightness sliders under Settings > Power](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405073/22-04-jammy-shows-no-brightness-sliders-under-settings-power)
and this
[Ubuntu 22.04 after update screen brightness control disappeared from the bar and brightness is at 100%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481435/ubuntu-22-04-after-update-screen-brightness-control-disappeared-from-the-bar-and/1488861#1488861))

Tried above ideas but nothing changed after reboot.
Any ideas?
Some say firmwares or graphics card driver but that i don't how to go about troubleshooting those.

kernel: 6.2.0-34-generic
Lenovo ThinkCentre M720q
firmware version: M1UKT65A
graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
Ubuntu 23.04
gnome 44.3

Thanks a million to any helper! :)